# php mysql array sorting

Tags: php, sorting, arraylist

I have an array that holds the name and the price of the inventory.
I want to check the customer order against the price_list and out put the total price for this order.

This the main price list:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM price_list WHERE id='1'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$data = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) )
{
    $t_name = $row['name'];
    $t_price = $row['price'];

    $t_array[] = array( "name" => $t_name, "price" => $t_price );
}
```

This is the customer order in the mysql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE id='1'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) )
{
    $pants = $row['pants'];
    $shirt = $row['shirt'];
    $hat = $row['hat'];
}
```

and if this I echo the above, it would look like this:
    blue jean, black pants,
    white shirt (X2), red shirt,
    black hat, grey hat

The (X2) doesn't exist in the price_list and I have to match the white shirt in the price_list and then multiply it by 2.
This (X2) could be changed dynamically to any other item, depending on the order.
Also on the result, I would like to multiplay the price of the pants and the hat (not the shirt) by a variable like `$discount`, which could ba a discount rate.

I have to mention that this order came through jquery and that is why the php doesn’t know about the total price.

Comment: in the ajax only the total price will be passed through...

Comment: add `$total = 0;` before the while loop, and `$total += $row['price'];` in the loop.

Comment: I guess this is too complicated and no one wants to touch it!

Comment: Be patient. You _will__ get help. It's a pity that you are new and can't offer a bounty. Try answering a few questions & work up some points. I don't use them to measure "how clever" I am, just to pay for bounties when I don't get a great answer ;-)

Comment: Btw, mysql_ functions are deprecated. You should be using http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Comment: "I have to mention that this order came through jquery and that is why the php doesn’t know about the total price" - but you will have to calculate individual item pricing, discounts, postage & total price on the server side. You can't leave that to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information with a single query using a JOIN statement.
But to cover your question completely (even remotely complete) would cover quite some broader topics (too big and broad to be answered here). And so I'll just leave you with a self-contained example to encourage you to delve deeper into some topics.... (e.g. the table/index structure is nowhere near "ready-for-production")

[sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');  
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

$stmt = $pdo->query('
    SELECT
        p.name, p.price, o.qty
    FROM
        soFooOrderItems as o
    JOIN
        soFooPriceList as p
    ON
        o.itemid = p.itemid
    WHERE
        o.orderid = 1
');

$total = 0;
foreach( $stmt as $row ) {
    $subtotal = bcmul($row['qty'], $row['price'], 2);
    printf("%s (%d pcs) | %s per pc. | %s\r\n",
        $row['name'],
        $row['qty'],
        $row['price'],
        $subtotal
    );
    $total = bcadd($total, $subtotal, 2);
}
echo 'total: ', $total;


function setup($pdo) {
    $queries = array(
        '
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFooPriceList (
                itemid INT,
                name varchar(32),
                price Decimal(6,2)
            )
        ',
        '
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFooOrderItems (
                orderid int,
                itemid  int,
                qty int
            )
        ',
        "INSERT INTO soFooPriceList (itemid, name, price) VALUES (1, 'blue jeans', 2.0), (2, 'Disruptor MkIII', 870.5), (3, 'black pants', 1.4), (4, 'Emergency Transport Beacon', 600.75), (5, 'white shirt', 1.0)",
        "INSERT INTO soFooOrderItems (orderid,itemid, qty) VALUES
            (1,1,1), (1,3,2), (1,5,1),
            (2,2,1), (2,4,1), (2,1,1)
        ",
    );
    foreach( $queries as $q ) {
        $pdo->exec($q);
    }
}
```

prints

```
blue jeans (1 pcs) | 2.00 per pc. | 2.00
black pants (2 pcs) | 1.40 per pc. | 2.80
white shirt (1 pcs) | 1.00 per pc. | 1.00
total: 5.80
```

Comment: VolkerK, thank you for your guide and the sample code! I have been trying to do this many different ways which needless to say that didn't work... I will try this and hopefully will get it work.